# View graph figure powerlaw distribution graph in Python

Tags: python, plot, graph

I am using powerlaw distribution package for plotting data into powerlaw in python (pycharm). I need to view the graph of the plotted data.

How can I achieve this? Here's the code:

```
import powerlaw

fit = powerlaw.Fit(data)
print fit.power_law.alpha
print fit.power_law.sigma
print fit.power_law.xmin

R, p = fit.distribution_compare('power_law','exponential')
print R, p
fig2 = fit.plot_pdf(color = '-b', linewidth = 2)
fit.power_law.plot_pdf(color = '-b', ax = fig2)
```

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to draw a plot in order to compare the powerlaw and exponential ccdf functions.

If by *" view the graph of the plotted data"* you mean "view the plot of the **fit** data", you could simply add the following:

```
fit.exponential.plot_pdf(color = '-b', ax = fig2)
```

Note that you need to import matplotlib.pyplot.